# Monitoring Records Updating from dataloader

Tags: data-loader

I have to do false update on opportunity.I am doing through dataloader. How can i monitor the records behavior. How would i know if trigger got broke.
Would in success error files records it will give error if any error occurred.

Comment: If you run debug logs or have developer console running then you can get the stack trace easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in the success/error files it wold display which records have failed and what is the error behind the fail. Generally the error message seems to be relatively smaller than what would you normally get if you updated the records manually. If you want to track what triggers are failing it would be good to include either `try and catch` statements or `system.debug()` statements after each major change so you can visualize better what is causing the error. After each triggered event ( record insert, update , delete etc) you should also be able to view the debug logs.

Comment: You can also use breakpoints through your code and check if you want to check the status on a certain point of your code.

Comment: Thanks Alexander,I guess Breakpoints is not enable in our org.It requires some licence,please let me know if salesforce has made that available through any other way.